# Does anyone have any suggestions beyond the Windows MediaPlayer class for embedding video or audio?

Tags: c#, audio, video, media-player, axwindowsmediaplayer

I'm writing an application that is intended to embed audio or preferably video in a windows form.

Right now I am using the standard MediaPlayer class (xWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer MediaPlayer)  and am finding that it may not have some of the functionality that I am hoping for.

One of the features I would like to have in this application is 'unadulterated scrubbing' of said audio or video... Which in this context I would define as 'the ability to scrub the video without stopping playback' - or otherwise, continuing to play audio or video While scrubbing...

Examples of this can be seen in programs such as Adobe Premier; in which you can scrub the position of your video on the timeline, and at whatever rate you are scrubbing, it will play back some 'garbled' audio.

The intention in this feature is to grant someone the ability to ( using a foot pedal, in one instance ) roll back in the media and know exactly where they are, based on audio feedback...

This particular feature is very specific and debatable in its ability to be achieved, but the core of the question here is this; What would be your suggestions for a 'more fully featured' media player that can be utilized in a C# windows form?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Standard Video/Audio APIs are all native: DirectShow, Media Foundation. .NET wrappers exist. The mentioned is doable, but not, however, available out of the box or close.

Comment: Very well... I appreciate the tip; it sounds like I'm about to be writing my own DirectShow wrapper... I'm still open to more suggestions! Lol